# python でlinux コマンドを起動 -- subprocessでオプションに "=" が必要な場合

Tags: python, linux, python3, centos

python でlinux コマンドを起動させる際の質問が2つあります。
2つを別々のスレッドで質問します。
まず1つめ。

subprocess モジュールのsubprocess.check_output()を用いて
コマンド touch を使用しようとしていますが、オプション"--date= " を使うには
どのようにすればよいですか?
"-t"オプションのように"="がいらないタイプなら

```
subprocess.check_output(["touch", "-a", "-t", date1, filename])
```

のように、リストを渡すことで実現できますが、"--date="オプションのように、
"="が必要なタイプのオプションはどのように用いればよいですか?

環境
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
Python: Python 3.6.5

Comment: 書式の変更はともかく、文面の変更はご遠慮ください。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローにおける編集の扱いに関して、 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49578/3054 のほうでコメントいたしました。ご理解いただければと思います。

Comment: PicoSushiさんによる編集が優れていると考えますので、ロールバックいたしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日付を指定する文字列をシングルクォートで囲う必要はありません．

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["touch", "-m", "--date=2018-10-24 22:00:00", "filename"])

$ ls -al filename 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hoge hoge 0 10月 24 22:00 filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Linuxコマンドを起動するコマンドラインの引数は、空白などで区切られた文字列の配列として各コマンドに渡されます。「--date=tomorrow」のようなコマンド引数は、それで1つの文字列になります。

つまり、こんな感じで指定します。

```
subprocess.check_output(["touch", "-a", "--date=tomorrow", filename])
```

Comment: res1=subprocess.check_output(["touch", "-m", "--date='2018-10-24 22:00:00'", filename]) を実行すると、touch: `\'2018-10-24 22:00:00\'': 無効な日付の書式です と言われ、エラーになります...

Comment: res1=subprocess.check_output(["touch", "-m", "--date=2018-10-24 22:00:00", filename]) でどうでしょう