# python でlinux コマンドを起動 — subprocessでパイプ、リダイレクトがある場合

Tags: python, linux, python3, centos

python でlinux コマンドを起動させる際の質問が2つあります。
2つめです。

subprocess モジュールのsubprocess.check_call()を用いる際に
複数のコマンドをパイプで接続したり、リダイレクトしたり
することはできますか?

実行したいことは、例えば

```
nkf -wLu file1 > file2
```

のようなことをsubprocess.check_call()で実現したいということです。
今のところ、仕方ないので

```
#! /usr/bin/sh
nkf -wLu $1 > $2
```

のようなシェルスクリプトsample.sh を作り、

```
subprocess.check_call(['sample.sh', file1, file2])
```

のような形で実現しています。
とはいえ、もっとスマートな方法があればと思い、質問させていただきました。

環境
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Python: Python 3.6.5

Comment: スマートかどうかは分かりませんが、`shell=True` を指定してみてはどうでしょうか。`subprocess.check_call("nkf -wLu %s > %s" % (file1, file2), shell=True)`

Comment: 書式の変更はともかく、文面の変更はご遠慮ください。

Comment: 文面を変更したのは私ではないです。

Comment: metropolisさん、失礼致しました

Comment: @SusumuYoshida スタック・オーバーフローにおいては、投稿は第三者による編集が可能で推奨されています。詳しくは、[「自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか?編集はどのように機能しますか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)をご覧下さい。自分の投稿を編集されるというのは他のプラットフォームではあまり無いことで、ぎょっとされたかも知れませんが、スタック・オーバーフローの投稿は回答者や編集者を含めた大勢で作る共同制作物であると、ご理解いただければと思います。もちろん、編集が投稿を改善していないとお考えの場合は、ロールバックや再編集を行なうことが出来ます。

Comment: さて、今回のPicoSushiさんの編集内容ですが、「No2」という質問者さんの質問時点の文脈に依存する部分を具体的にして、質問者さん以外にも伝わり易いように改善されています。また、[2名によってレビュー済み](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20521)でもあります。
スタック・オーバーフローにおいては、このような編集は歓迎されるものと考えますので、この編集時点へロールバックさせていただきました。
「いや、そうでは無くてNo2の方が伝わり易い理由があるので、この編集は改善になっていない」ということでしたら、[Metaサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)の方でお意見いただければと思います。

Comment: metropolisさん、確認できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: タイトルは質問内容が簡潔に説明されていることが望ましいです。ぜひヘルプも参照してみてください。 - "タイトルは、回答者になるかもしれない人が最初に目にするもので、タイトルが興味深くなければその続きは読みません。" [ヘルプ : 質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: cubickさんのコメントにあるヘルプから、PicoSushiさんによる編集が優れていると考えますので、ロールバックいたしました。

Comment: 投稿がどうあるべきかの議論については、興味もないですし、参戦する意図もありません。時間の無駄です。この投稿がトラブルの原因となるなら削除させていただきます。解決にご協力いただいた方々には感謝申し上げます。

Comment: 時間の無駄と言われたらそこまでなんですが、ぜひご一読ください。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: 時間の無駄だからMetaでは議論しないけど、これはsubprocess.check_call()だけの問題ではなく、linux コマンドの起動の問題なので、PicoSushiさんの編集は改悪だと思っています。

Comment: では、「タイトルに質問内容を簡潔に説明されている」よう修正ください。No.2では回答しようとする人には何のことか・・・

Comment: edit warの様相になってしまい申し訳ありません。「stackoverflow の原理原則」「知見を Q&A で集積」「Be Nice」を尊重していただければと思います。@SusumuYoshida さん、ご一読ください。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2682/#2684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(file2, "w") as f:
    subprocess.check_call(['nkf', '-wLu', file1], stdout=f)
```

なお、パイプで接続したい場合は、公式ドキュメント「subprocess --- サブプロセス管理」のページの[「シェルのパイプラインを置き換える」](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)の項を参考にしてしてください。

Comment: 参考までに：本家SOでもこの方式が最多の票を集めているようです https://stackoverflow.com/a/6482200/10216107

Comment: ありがとうございました。確認できました。